# Solving non-linear ODE with cosine term

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, differential-equations

I want to find an equation of motion for non-uniform circular motion under the inlfuence of gravity (like, say, a pendulum) of the form **r**(*t*)=*R* cos⁡(*θ*(*t*)) **i** + *R* sin⁡(*θ*(*t*)) **j** where $\theta (t) $ is only influenced by gravity, and is measured like a trigonometric angle in the unit circle (counter-clockwise from x axis).

[image]

The Lagrangian of the system would be:

$$ 
L = \frac{1}{2}m{R^2}{\dot \theta ^2} - mgR\sin \theta
$$

I'd then apply the E-L equation and get:

$$
\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial \theta }} =  - mgR\cos \theta
$$
$$
\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial \dot \theta }} = m{R^2}\dot \theta
$$

$$
\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial \dot \theta }}} \right) = m{R^2}\ddot \theta
$$

And the differential equation I'd need to solve would be:

$$
\ddot \theta  =  - \frac{g}{R}\cos \theta 
$$

The initial conditions I had in mind were that $ \dot \theta (t=0) = \dot \theta _0 $ while $ \theta (t=0) = 0$.

I, however, have no clue how to deal with the cosine term. I know that this non-linear ODE has no analytical solution, but I have no clue how to approximate it either. I cannot use small angles because I want $ \theta $ to be able to do a full circle.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: If you don't want to make an approximation you could just solve it numerically using Eulers method or RK4

Comment: since there is no analytical solution you have to do it numerically. but you can find numerical solutions as graphs in the net

Comment: *I know that this non-linear ODE has no analytical solution* It does have an analytic solution in terms of the Jacobi elliptic sine function sn. See http://www.pgccphy.net/ref/nonlin-pendulum.pdf

Comment: Your initial conditions are strange. You want to call the initial angular velocity $\theta_0$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $ \dot \theta (0) = \dot \theta _0$.

Comment: [Exact solution for thé non-linear pendulum.](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1806-11172007000400024)

Comment: @Farcher The initial conditions in the papers you and I have linked to are different from the OP’s initial conditions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  $E=\frac 12  \dot \theta^2+ V(\theta)$ being constant and separate variables to  get something like 
$$
\int_0^t dt +const. = \int_0^{\theta(t)}  \frac{ d\theta}{\sqrt{2(V(\theta)-E)}},
$$
but, except for the case that the pendulum starts at rest at the topmost point, you are looking at an elliptic integral on the RHS.  The start-at-top case is easy though. The answer (measuring $\theta$ from the topmost point) is
$$
\theta(t)= 4 \tan^{-1} (e^{At})
$$
for some constant $A$ depending on $m$, $g$, $R$ etc. The general solution requires Jacobi functions.

Comment: Pretty sure the constant $A$ won't depend on $m$.  Also, the kinetic energy should be $\frac{1}{2} m R^2 \dot{\theta}^2$.

Comment: I set all constants to unity. The OP should do the algbera :)

Comment: In that case, the constant $A$ should be a function of 1, 1, 1, etc.  :-)

Comment: If it starts at rest at the top, it just stays there, in unstable equilibrium, as shown in the 6th example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Examples).

Comment: @G.Smith At top plus $\epsilon$...  It takes infinitely long for the $\theta(t)=4\tan^{-1} (e^t)$ to make the round trip.  This is the space part of the Sine-Gordon Soliton solution.